# My website contact form placeholders not displaying properly only on one of our computers

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, contacts

I am building a website, in which I have a contact form.
I have tested it on all browsers, and on mobile, ipad and desktop.
Firefox developers edition also has a multi-device resposiveness tester, that I tried and all devices work fine.

Then I uploaded the website on a temporary host, for testing purposes, and tested it again, all fine!
Except for one of the laptops on our office, where the placeholders appear as lines and dots.

I can't find any problem with the code,
Can you help?

```
    <!--Contact Form-->

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome" required data-error="Por favor escreva o seu nome">
                                                <div class="help-block with-errors">
                                                </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <input type="email" class="email form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" required data-error="Por favor escreva o seu email">
                                                <div class="help-block with-errors">
                                                </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <input type="text" id="msg_subject" name="msg_subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Assunto" required data-error="Por favor escreva o assunto da mensagem">
                                                <div class="help-block with-errors">
                                                </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <textarea id="message" name="message" rows="7" placeholder="Mensagem" class="form-control" required data-error="Escreva a sua mensagem"></textarea>
                                                <div class="help-block with-errors">
                                                </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-effect"><i class="fa fa-check"></i>Enviar</button>
                                        <div id="msgSubmit" class="h3 text-center hidden">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="clearfix">
                                        </div>
                            </form>


    section#contact .form-group input, section#contact .form-group textarea {
    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
    border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
    font-size: 13px;
}
.form-control {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #555;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
    -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,-webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    -o-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
```

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Comment: can you post full page?like you have missing the style tag as well.